# Cannot get modal to load on page load. The standard bootstrap method is not working. and cant figure out why

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

So I am trying to get a modal to load on page load. This should be a fairly standard and routine excercise, yet it refuses to work! It works on click just fine.

The bootstrap and jquery scripts are loaded as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

The code for loading the modal on page load is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).on('load',function(){
          $('#firstEvent').modal('show');
      });
</script>
```

Its the last thing in the header section.

In the body, the modal is defined as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="firstEvent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Came Here to Live:</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" arialabel="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h5>Resilience and Resistance in the Containment Zone</h5>
            <p> Came Here to Live offers a vision of what is possible when we build new models for an inclusive and just society, embrace our intrinsic interdependence, and see our futures as interconnected.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://abdproductions.us14.list-manage.com/track/click?u=7236fd78e87c77b23342edecd&id=38b8a0ef9b&e=d9d32ec828'">Purchase tickets</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the script in head section or the bottom of page? You should wrap jquery inside documnt.ready.

Comment: could you elaborate? I've tried the jquery as the last thing before the </body> tag and the last thing before the </head> tag. No go either way.

Answer (score 0):

whoops.. caught it. the modal id should be in double quotes!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).on('load',function(){
          $("#firstEvent").modal('show');
      });
</script>
```

it works now!!